# Perl: syntax for using variables in quotes

Tags: perl

In a quote, how can you seperate variables from other text:

Example, I want to print "YellowBrick":

```
my $var = 'Yellow';

print "$varBrick";

# $varBrick not defined!!
```

You can use:

```
print "@{[$var]}Brick"
```

What I don't understand is the syntax: are all 5 characeters (`@{[]}`) needed every time you escape one variable? Is there any significance of @ {} or the []'s? Is this making an array then a ref to an aarray or something?

Basically my question is what other tricks can be done with the `@{[]}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@{[...]}` isn't needed. You simply need

```
print "${var}Brick";
```

or

```
print $var."Brick";
```

---

`"@{ EXPR }"` interpolates the array referenced by the reference returned by the expression.

`[ LIST ]` is the array constructor. It returns a reference to a new array initialized by assigning the list inside the brackets to the array.

This means that

```
"@{[$var]}Brick"
```

is the same as

```
"@{ my @anon = $var; \@anon }Brick"
```

Obviously, the solutions I presented above are much better. `@{[...]}` would allow you to embed Perl code in the string literal.

```
"...@{[ uc($var) ]}..."
```

If it's just one scalar, one could also use the following:

```
"...${\ uc($var) }..."
```

That said, I prefer to use concatenation instead of creating needless references.

```
"...".( uc($var) )."..."   # The parens aren't needed here.
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple scalars, you can just use braces as delimiters:

```
"${var}Brick"
```

`@{[]}` is a hack that allows the interpolation of arbitrary expressions.  Just as it would outside a string, `@{ $x }` treats `$x` as an array reference and dereferences it.  `[]` is the anonymous array reference constructor.  So the formulation

```
"@{[ $var ] }Brick"
```

says "Make a string.  Start by building an anonymous array reference containing the value of `$var`, then turn this reference into an array containing the value of `$var`, then interpolate that array of one element into the string and follow it with the literal string 'Brick'."

Note that because `"@{[ ... ]}"` relies upon array interpolation, if `...` is a list value it is subject to `$LIST_SEPARATOR`.

Answer (score 2):

The real trick is that further interpolation can be done.  For instance, consider, @{[sprintf("%.02f",$var)]}.  As Aniket implies, there's usually little reason to use something like this, but it can be useful in, for example, here documents, where you can't jump out of the quotes for interpolating something and then back in.  All in all, it's probably not the best idea to use this as it may confound others trying to understand your code.  But it is a neat trick.

Answer (score -1):

why not `print $var."brick"`?.. keep it simple :-)

Comment: The purpose of question is how to use a variable *inside* quotes, not outside of quotes.